# How to place scanned images in proper position

Tags: floats

[image]

In my latex i can not place the scanned images in proper positions like after each paragraph i have to give proper pages
This is i have done:

```
     \section{conclusions}
     \subsection{Appendix-A}


     \begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_122916.jpg}
      %\caption{$y=x$}
       %\label{fig:y equals x}
     \end{subfigure}

      %\caption{Three simple graphs}
       %\label{fig:three graphs}
       \end{figure}
       \begin{figure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_150926.jpg}
      %\caption{$y=3sinx$}
      %\label{fig:three sin x}
      \end{subfigure}

      %\caption{Three simple graphs}
       %\label{fig:three graphs}
      \end{figure}
      \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_151003.jpg}
    %\caption{$y=x$}
    %\label{fig:y equals x}
    \end{subfigure}


   %\caption{Three simple graphs}
   %\label{fig:three graphs}
  \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_151038.jpg}
    %\caption{$y=x$}
    %\label{fig:y equals x}
\end{subfigure}


%\caption{Three simple graphs}
%\label{fig:three graphs}
 \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_151114.jpg}
    %\caption{$y=x$}
    %\label{fig:y equals x}
\end{subfigure}


%\caption{Three simple graphs}
%\label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_151147.jpg}
    %\caption{$y=x$}
    %\label{fig:y equals x}
\end{subfigure}


%\caption{Three simple graphs}
%\label{fig:three graphs}
 \end{figure}
\subsection{Appendix-B}
\paragraph{B.1 Feynman rules for Majorana Spinors:}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_112008.jpg}
        %\caption{$y=x$}
        %\label{fig:y equals x}
    \end{subfigure}

    %\caption{Three simple graphs}
    %\label{fig:three graphs}
     \end{figure}
      \paragraph{B.2 Tree Level contribution to $N_k\rightarrow       l\overline{\phi}$ :}
      \begin{figure}
      \centering
       \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_112113.jpg}
        %\caption{$y=x$}
        %\label{fig:y equals x}
        \end{subfigure}
        \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_112224.jpg}
        %\caption{$y=3sinx$}
        %\label{fig:three sin x}
       \end{subfigure}
       \end{figure}
       \subsection{Appendix-C}
       \paragraph{C.1 Vertex contribution to the CP asymmetry:}
        \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_211454.jpg}
        %\caption{$y=x$}
        %\label{fig:y equals x}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
     \begin{figure}
     \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_211554.jpg}
    %\caption{$y=x$}
    %\label{fig:y equals x}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
     \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_211635.jpg}
    %\caption{$y=x$}
    %\label{fig:y equals x}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    \paragraph{C.2 Self energy contribution to the CP asymmetry:}
     \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_112406.jpg}
        %\caption{$y=x$}
        %\label{fig:y equals x}
    \end{subfigure}
     \end{figure}
     \begin{figure}
      \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_20190710_112651.jpg}
    %\caption{$y=x$}
    %\label{fig:y equals x}
    \end{subfigure}
     \end{figure}
```

Comment: You're going to need to show us the code that you're using to place the image.  Offhand, my guess would be that you shouldn't be using the `figure` environment, because you don't want the figure to float anywhere.  (Which would have nothing to do with scanning.)

Comment: It would have been much more helpful if you had supplied code to show what you are doing.  But I will guess that you are using a `figure` environment.  Don't.  That will float to where LaTeX thinks it fits best (geometrically, not contextually).  `\includegraphics` doesn't require this.  Instead, you can embed it in a `center` environment exactly where you want it.

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).  You could convert your scanned images to PDF and include them with [pdfpages](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)